# Export Antivirus informations into file.csv in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I tried to get Antivirus informations and to export it in a file.csv. In the AVName result, I got `system.object[]` because it is an array. Any idea to fix it ?

```
Get-Content "C:\Temp\computers.txt"  | ForEach-Object {
    $av_name=$null
    $errorMsg=''
    Try {
        $av_name = (Get-CimInstance -Namespace root/SecurityCenter2 -ClassName AntivirusProduct).displayName
    }
    catch {
        $errorMsg=$_.Exception.Message
    }
    if(!$av_name) {
        $av_name = "The machine is not protected $errorMsg"
        $av_name = "The machine is not protected"
    }
    else {
        $av_name = (Get-CimInstance -Namespace root/SecurityCenter2 -ClassName AntivirusProduct).displayName
    }
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        ComputerName = $_
        AVName = $av_name
    } | Select-Object ComputerName,AVName | Export-Csv "C:\Temp\AV_Details.csv" -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, the mistake is that the `Export-Csv` cmdlet is one closing curly bracket too high up.
Also, there is no need to perform `(Get-CimInstance -Namespace root/SecurityCenter2 -ClassName AntivirusProduct).displayName` twice and you do not need to use `Select-Object` when you output objects with just the two properties you are selecting afterwards.

Try

```
Get-Content "C:\Temp\computers.txt"  | ForEach-Object {
    # store this in a variable, because $_ will become the exception object inside the catch when things go wrong
    $computer = $_  
    $av_name  = $null
    $errorMsg = ''
    Try {
        $av_name = (Get-CimInstance -Namespace root/SecurityCenter2 -ClassName AntivirusProduct -ComputerName $computer).displayName -join '; '
    }
    catch {
        $errorMsg = $_.Exception.Message
    }
    if(!$av_name) {
        $av_name = "The machine is not protected $errorMsg"
    }

    [PsCustomObject]@{
        ComputerName = $computer
        AVName       = $av_name
    }
} | Export-Csv "C:\Temp\AV_Details.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

---

on my machine, with a computers.txt file only containing the IP address, I get output like:

```
"ComputerName","AVName"
"192.168.0.10","Windows Defender"
```

Comment: The text file "computers.txt" contains list of IPs used as entries (for this exemple, I only have my IP in the file). The resuslt should be the list on Antivirus installed on the machine but I have now a liste of numbers that I don(t even know what they are

Comment: @ElhadjiDIOP Works for me though.. What version of PowerShell are you using? `Get-CimInstance` is only available as from PS version 3.0. If your version is older, you need to use `$av_name = (Get-WmiObject -Namespace root/SecurityCenter2 -Class AntivirusProduct -ComputerName $computer).displayName` instead.

Comment: @ElhadjiDIOP Then I can't see why you say it doesn't work when it does for me.. Can you show us the output you're getting?

Comment: I am using PowerShell 5.1.19041.1023 which  supports Get-CimInstance. 
Get-CimInstance -Namespace root/SecurityCenter2 -ClassName AntivirusProduct -ComputerName $computer shows me 2 Antivirus, so it's working fine on CLI but note when I try to export on file.csv

Comment: @ElhadjiDIOP You're not showing **what** you are getting in the output file.. Are you sure you're looking in the correct file? On my machine it creates AV_Details like I have edited in the answer.

Comment: I get as an output in the file.csv
"Length"
58
23
18

Comment: @ElhadjiDIOP Then you did not copy/paste my code correctly or your input file is not what you say it is.. The code creates an array of objects which gets piped to `Export-Csv`. If the code should produce something else, like a string you would get such a result.  Please double-check your input file (does it have weird characters, what is the encoding, are there empty lines, etc) and copy the code again and paste in the ISE or VsCode editor **exactly** as is.

Comment: I copied/posted your code but now the error is about WinRm and it's like it can't reach the IP (my machine). It comes from the ```$computer = $_``` I guess

Comment: @ElhadjiDIOP yes, when probing your own pc, you need to remove `-ComputerName $computer` to avoid the winrm/kerberos/trusted machine error.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. But if I add ``` ConvertTo-Csv``` , I got the same numbers as results. If I remove it, I have ``` system.object[]```

Comment: You don't get that error because you only have 1 Antivirus. I have Windows Defender and Sentinel that's why the ``` system.object[] ``` occurs.

Comment: The file.csv shows ComputerName, "AVName"
                             192.168.53.3,       "System.object[]"

Comment: @ElhadjiDIOP Aha, now I understand the problem. I have added ` -join '; '` at the end of the `(Get-CimInstance ...).displayName` line, so that if there are multiple antivirus applications, these will be joined with a semi-colon. Of course, you ca change that into something else if you like.

Comment: You really helped me, It worked when I added ``` -join "" ``` and I have now both Antivirus installed. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

[ConvertTo-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv?view=powershell-7.1)

Add this here

```
} | Select-Object ComputerName,AVName |*AddMe*| Export-Csv "C:\Temp\AV_Details.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer
I tried with the " *AddMe* " but it makes an error saying that command is not recognized.
when I remove it, I am facing the same system.object[] error